Change the "no file selected." on return of file upload
I have the following code for loading a file:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="ControllerX" method="post">
    <dl>      
        <dd>
            <input name="file" type="file">
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>


When I select the file to load it writes the name of the file in place of "No file selected", this is great. When the Upload button is pressed the file is loaded and it returns to this page and the "No file Selected" is now displayed again. How do I get this to change to something like "File XXXX has been successfully loaded"
Thank you!

YOUR server code is creating that HTML, right?  So, YOU need to put it there.

I believe this is what you are looking for->


function displayFileName() {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
  const fileStatus = document.getElementById("fileStatus");

  if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
    fileStatus.textContent = `Selected file: ${fileInput.files[0].name}`;
  } else {
    fileStatus.textContent = "No file selected";
  }
}


document.getElementById("uploadForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");

  if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("fileStatus").textContent = `File ${fileInput.files[0].name} has been successfully loaded`;
    setTimeout(() => this.submit(), 1000);
  }
});
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="ControllerX" method="post" id="uploadForm">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input id="fileInput" name="file" type="file" onchange="displayFileName()">
      <p id="fileStatus">No file selected</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>



If you want to customize it more, i would suggest you remove the "no file choosen" text that comes default for file type inputs and use the new custom text that updates based on state.
